# Saving Android Instance

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to save a variable so that i can use that variable and render it later when the user opens the app again.
Currently i am using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState functions for the same. It is working fine while rotating the screen(i.e. the variable value is same in portrait and landscape mode). But after closing the app and then again launching the app, the variable is again going back to zero.

In my code i want store the **count** variable

```
 var count=0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            Log.d("chola","chola")
            count=savedInstanceState.getInt("hola")
        }
        Log.d("dola","dola")
        show()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        Log.d("hola","hola")
        outState.putInt("hola",count)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("chola","chola")
        count=savedInstanceState.getInt("hola")
//        tv1.setText(count.toString())
    }
private fun show(){
        tv1.setText(count.toString())
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use persistent storage if the data should be available even after closing the app.

Check [Docs here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

Your options are,

1. Shared Preferences or datastore
2. Local database
3. File storage
4. Remote Database.

Shared preference or data store would fit your use case.

Example code for shared preferences from Docs,

[Creating shared preference instance](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#GetSharedPreferences),

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

[Write to shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#WriteSharedPreference)

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore)
    apply()
}
```

[Read from shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#ReadSharedPreference)

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
val defaultValue = resources.getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key)
val highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue)
```